# gsh - Global Shell: Where do you put the shared keys, password?

Tags: perl, cluster-computing

I'm trying to use the `gsh` command on ubuntu to do some embarrassingly parallel stuff.  I've made an `/etc/ghosts` file containing all the IP addresses for the hosts, and each host has an account that I created just for "cluster" purposes.

However, when I try a command such as,

```
$ gsh -l cluster ok 'echo $host'
```

I get in return two errors,

```
hostn: Host key verification failed.

hostn+1: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)
```

I've already SSH'ed these computers and exchanged keys.  I can't find anything in the `gsh` man page about a key file.  Also, there is the question of where to put the password.

This is the version that I am using: http://outflux.net/software/pkgs/gsh/

If you can't answer, then maybe you can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `gsh` uses `ssh`. Therefore, you'll need to set up your `authorized_keys` file as explained in [OpenSSH Public Key Authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/).

Answer (score 1):

The "host verification error" is happening because SSH wants you to manually confirm that it's okay to connect to the remote server before you can SSH for the first time. GSH doesn't seem to have an option to override that, but you can:

1) edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config

2) uncomment the line starting "StrictHostKeyChecking"

3) Change the line to say "StrictHostKeyChecking **no**"

Obviously this compromises security to some extent, but it gets rid of the host verification error.